# In java, can "public static void main" be renamed or refactored?

Tags: java, refactoring, program-entry-point

I do not want to change the `public static void` ... `String[] args` part of the signature, but is it possible to "rename" this function (eg. just for fun)?

So the entry point for execution would be a function with another name.

Rename it to, like, `boot` (what would better reflect, if not being historical, the actual use for it in my particular case).

---

**related**

I'm interested in doing something different, but these questions are still interesting:

[public static void main(String arg[ ] ) in java is it fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028589/public-static-void-mainstring-arg-in-java-is-it-fixed)

[Why the name main for function main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688338/why-the-name-main-for-function-main)

Comment: Well, if you also change the code of the JVM then it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out possibility by [source] hacking. :) So is there no configurable way, then?

Comment: Why, a downvote for just being a little curious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) says:

> A Java virtual machine starts execution by invoking the method `main` of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings.

The [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) says the same thing:

> The Java virtual machine then links the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the public class method `void main(String[])`.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Answer No, Reason, [Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) is like that, `JVM` will only look for `main` and not any custom name as the starting point. It has to be called main with the exact signature `public static void main(String[] args)`

Logically also it makes sense how will `JVM` know that instead of `main` method, it has to look for `boot` or something else unless `java` command had an option to pass the start method.

But that is asking just too much for no good reason.

Secondly since its standardized it helps the developer community too, whoever looks at the code know how to run a given `Java` Standalone program, or say if you have got a project, your first point will always be look for the main method, and from there you move on.

Comment: It's good that it's standardized, but this should not be a showstopper as it still could have had a standardized a way to specify the name of the entry point.

Comment: One reason to do that would be better self-describing name for a central function. Although I admit it's arguable if main is not descriptive enough, and also we add that to it's overwhelmingly widespread usage.

Comment: as you correctly pointed out main is self describing too many flexibility becomes an overkill without much advantage gain in this case

Answer (score 2):

No. You can not do that according to Java Language Specification. But if you want, as Java is a open source project, so download the complete source code of Java language and change it accordingly ( I mean change the source code of JVM itself). This is the only way you can do that.

So now you can understand, why I said it is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

At start JVM is looking from method `public static void main` with array of Strings as argument. So only thing you can do is rename argument `args`. If you want method like boot nobody stops you from doing something like this (personally I don't recommend that "pattern")

```
static void boot(String[] arguments){
    //your logic
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boot(args);
}
```

Comment: nice code example. :) I'm doing it like this currently. I just always felt that the name `main` is actually not very descriptive nowadays. Sounds more like a historical artifact.

Comment: I got used to `main` method, so for me `boot` is just one unnecessary method call. But every human is free so won't stop you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your application starts running from `public static void main(String[] args)`. It's like the point where JVM looks at to start the proceedings. If you change it, JVM will feel free to not start your application.

If you want to want to have `boot()` as the starting point of your application - call it in `main()`.

Comment: Yes, calling `boot` is what I currently do. :) I just always felt that calling (ie. naming) it `main` is actually not a very descriptive name nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is `NO` . When you start executing program it looks for  `public static void main(String[] args)` which takes String  array argument.From this entry point **main thread** get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,We can change the name of the main method if we can change the configurations of the JVM and let it look for a method with another name instead of main method.

Comment: can you state the steps