# What does the "main()" that is put in the beginning of programs in C mean?

Tags: c

I just want to learn the basics thoroughly and what some simple codes refer to.

I was able to find a short description at 
https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/looking-at-the-c-language/ but I dont think I fully understand it with the help of just that.

Comment: It's the starting point of your program - where the operating system knows to go to start executing your code.

Comment: Is there any reason that it is "main" and not something like "start" or "beginning" instead, Im guessing theres not?

Comment: @scriptkiddie its because `crt0` calls `main` see: https://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean9/html/ch05s02.html

Comment: As to why it is called main take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688338/why-the-name-main-for-function-main

Comment: main is the first function executed that i s written by you - it isn't the first function executed because there is code that is run before your program starts that, for example. reads the command line and puts it into the argv array.

Comment: It's called `main` for the more or less the same reason you're called script kiddie.  It's not called `start` or `beginning` for more or less the same reason you're not called Tiggles or Sean the Avenger.

Comment: @scriptkiddie: The entry point needs to be called *something*.  `main` was as good a name as any, and it makes sense, as it’s the “main” part of your program.

Answer (score 1):

It's the starting point for your program.  [Per **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1):

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>      int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
>      int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
>   the following constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to
>     strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host
>     environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the
>     program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere
>     in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>     supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the
>     implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in
>     lowercase.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the
>     null character if the program name is not available from the host
>     environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings
>     pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program
>     parameters.
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their
>     last-stored values between program startup and program termination.